# How to add delay in the for loop?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

In here I'm trying to sort array of integers using insertion sort and print the array step by step according to the sorting mechanism. I want to have little delay between each sorting steps. I tried Thread.sleep and some other methods but couldn't find a solution. Please help me, I am a beginner in programming.

```
    public void insertionSort(int array[]){

        int j, k, key;

        for(j=1; j<array.length; j++){

            key = array[j];
            k = j-1;

            while(k>=0 && array[k]>key){
                array[k+1] = array[k];
                k = k-1;
            }
            array[k+1] = key;
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                txtArOutput.append(String.valueOf(arr[i])+"\t");
            }   
            txtArOutput.append("\n"); 
            //delay
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to increase a time of the method execution?

Comment: You want to 1) use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), and 2) [improve your search skills](https://www.google.com/webhp?rct=j#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+loop+delay)

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I just want to have little delay between each print statement, like a simulator

Answer (score 0):

hope this way helps

```
public class InsertionSortDemo extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JButton button;

    public InsertionSortDemo() {

        textArea = new JTextArea();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button = new JButton("Run Simulation");
        button.addActionListener( e -> {

            button.setEnabled(false);
            textArea.setText("");

            new Thread( () -> {

                Random r = new Random();

                int [] array = {

                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),
                        r.nextInt(100),

                };
                insertionSort(array);

            } ).start();

        } );

        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setContentPane(panel);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> new InsertionSortDemo() );
    }

    public void insertionSort(int array[]){

        int j, k, key;

        for(j=1; j<array.length; j++){

            key = array[j];
            k = j-1;

            while(k>=0 && array[k]>key){
                array[k+1] = array[k];
                k = k-1;
//                print(array);
            }
            array[k+1] = key;

            print(array);

            sleep(100);

        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> button.setEnabled(true) );

    }

    private void print(int array[]) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {

            for (int i : array) {
                textArea.append(i + ",");
            }
            textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());

        } );

    }

    private void sleep(long n) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can't I use this method to print output in a text area because I am using swing

Comment: It prints whole thing at once, no delay :(

Comment: hope this way helps